# Criar sistema operacional em batch (.bat)

Tags: batch, sistema-operacional

É possível criar um sistema operacional de verdade em *batch* (`.bat`)?
Pois vi alguns vídeos do Youtube em que o título era alguma coisa "OS in batch"(inglês).

Comment: Mostre a fonte para eu dar uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Fonte do vídeo?

Comment: Sim, claro.....

Comment: batch é um arquivo de lote do WINDOWS

Comment: Fiz uma pesquisa e acredito que esteja falando disso: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-OS-in-Batch-Language/ . Isto não se enquadra como um sistema Operacional, a resposta do @bigodow responde bem a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível por uma simples razão, para rodar um *script batch* precisa de um interpretador que precisa de um sistema operacional.

Uma simulação, algo complementar a um básico feito com outras tecnologias mais baixo nível, meio de brincadeira, até é possível.

Um sistema operacional tem que fazer acesso ao hardware, não é possível com algo tão primitivo. Claro que você pode chamar de sistema operacional algo que opera alguma coisa em mais alto nível de forma mais específica, mas não é o SO que a computação define.

O que eu achei pesquisando é uma simulação do que seria um sistema operacional, mesmo assim de forma muito incipiente, ou seja, é só uma brincadeira, não um SO de verdade.